# What is the difference between "In the manner of" and "in the way of"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I saw in a grammar book that the phrase **'in the manner of'** in the following sentence should be corrected as **'in the way of'**. Can anyone explain in details the difference between the two? Thanks.

> *"Through the sessions they not only facilitate better communication skills in the workplace, but also look into the problems **in the manner of** being able to convey messages effectively."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although ***way*** and ***manner*** are synonyms when they both refer to

`A method in which to do something` ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/way.html))

the idiomatic phrase needed here is ***in the way of*** or ***by way of***. The phrase means

`constituting; as a form of`  ([Oxford dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03DZJiAnf5lv9jJWOUnTL7EfB8Tvg%3A1609408012818&source=hp&ei=DJ7tX778L92GjLsP48GaqAw&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAX-2sHGngaxXYAiCl5rFA1oz0k-i3ebGQ&q=in%20the%20way%20of%20meaning&oq=in%20the%20way%20of%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQyQMyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoICAAQsQMQgwE6DgguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgIILjoFCAAQsQM6BAgjECc6CAgAELEDEMkDOgUILhCxAzoICC4QsQMQgwE6CAguEMcBEK8BUJaaSVjR5klgvulJaABwAHgAgAGzAYgBgRCSAQUxMS4xMJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi-spqH-PftAhVdA2MBHeOgBsUQ4dUDCAo&uact=5))

Here are other examples:

> His parents offered him little in the way of emotional support. (*little emotional support)*
>
> How much money has she received in the way of campaign contributions? (*that money is contributing to the campaign*)

***In the manner of*** is also an idiomatic phrase and it means

`in the style of a particular person or thing` [(Macmillan)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in-the-manner-of#:%7E:text=in%20the%20manner%20of%20%E2%80%8B,the%20manner%20of%20a%20hypnotist.)

So you would use it in a sentence like

> He told us the news ***in the manner of*** (like) someone who had just lost a loved one. Why wasn't he more excited?

Comment: I wonder why you use both quotes and `this thingy`.

Comment: Oh, shouldn't I? I tend to overemphasise things, but I guess it's not necessary.

Comment: You can use, but tbh, `it` looks ugly.  You can simply embolden them. :)

Comment: Well, I guess that is subjective. The site provides it, so I don't think there is a problem. I just want to differentiate examples from quoted definitions and from other things I have emboldened. But thank you for the remark, I also like to be "esthetic" :)